# How to delete a resource symbol in visual studio after deleting menu item, when it says "in use"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How do I delete a resource symbol in Visual Studio 2010 (Visual C++) if I delete a menu item and want to delete the resource symbol associated with that menu item...

The IDE says the symbol is still in use in the Resource Symbols dialog, even though I have deleted the menu item.

I made a video showing the behavior of visual studio which says the resource 
symbol is still "in use" even though from what I can see it is not in use. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9RB5Q2RuF4

It is not mandatory that you watch the video, I made it simply because it proves that I am not just imagining things or describing the problem incorrectly.  The only real way to prove peculiar IDE behaviour is to show a video of the editor making its mistakes or showing its problems.

Comment: It's probably still in use in your code (where the menu was processed).  Remove that and then try again.

Comment: Richard Critten, I have not added any actual code to the project, I have done nothing but visual development without any coding. Is there still a place where it is in use in the code even though I have not done any coding in the project yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the header file manually and delete the line containing the ID.

I found it best to do this in another editor (i.e. Notepad++). When you switch back to Visual Studio it will say "File edited by another program", just click reload. It will give an error if you deleted an ID that's actually in use. In that case undo your changes in the other editor and re-save. Then you may have to reopen visual studio to get it to reload the files.

It's not the ideal solution (I found this question because I was searching for a better one) but it at least resolves the problem.

Comment: should this bug be reported to Microsoft? Has it been fixed in recent versions of visual studio?

Comment: Well your report is with Visual Studio 2010 and I found this post trying to fix it in 2013 so I'd say it hasn't been fixed. You could report it as a bug if you want.

Comment: Actually, in VS2013 you can choose to right-click on an *.rc or resource.h file and click View Code. This will ask you if you want to close the file that was opened in another editor (resource editor, in my case) and you can do what you like, no need for notepad++. You can view *.rc and *.h side by side, search in *.rc, and if not found, delete from *.h. That's how I do it, at least. I've been using VS2010 Express (no res editor), now I have 2013 Ultimate, and frankly, it's a mess-making letdown.

Comment: Same thing happens in VS 2022. All I need to do is to tell VS that the *.rc file has been changed outside the "Resource Symbols" dialog (give *.rc a newer last modified time, no need to change the content), then "Resource Symbols" will show correct "In Use" state. **Several ways to achieve this:** 1. "View Code" the *.rc file, save it without modify anything, close it, reopen it by double clicking. 2. Open the *.rc file in any other text editor, save it. 3. "touch" the *.rc file in WSL.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>A recent edit of the question makes this answer irrelevant. However I'm not going to *chase a changing question*.</sup>

Edit → Resource Symbols…

<sup>Disclaimer: I have not watched the linked to video. Please do consider that some people may have low bandwidth connections. Also consider google-ability of what you post. A link to offsite information is not googleable. Post all relevant information *here*, and *as text* (in a few cases enlightening small screenshots can be good).</sup>

Comment: I am using the resource symbols dialog but it says in use.  See my video of the behavior on youtube in the original question.

Comment: @LOlson: please do **describe the problem in text**. do not link to off-site descriptions. do not use large images or worse, videos. think. please.

Comment: I have described the problem in text, the video is just a replica of my text

Comment: Re "the video is just a replica of my text", in that case, why are you referring to the video, "See my video", if it isn't relevant? think, please.

Comment: or rather the video is to prove my text is correct and that I am not just imagining things. In this case, screenshots do not do the question any justice, I would have to put up a lot of them, and it would not prove the behavior of the IDE. If you have low bandwidth, simply ignore the video. It helps people who do have bandwidth, which 95 percent of people do.

Comment: I think your edit, introducing a mention of the Resource Symbols... dialog, proves that your video was not just "prove[ing] that my text is correct", but rather, had crucial information about the nature of your problem. So much that the edit rendered this answer irrelevant. Please do think. But thanks for the edit. It may help others who want to help you.